# How to serve a podcast with byte-range (for iTunes connect)

Tags: node.js, byte, podcast

I added code for a NodeJS server to serve podcast episodes. I did not program byte-range requests and it is not validated by iTunes Connect. I built the XML file with the `rss` package, although I could have written it by hand. The relevant code is:

```js
/**
 * GET /podcast/:dayId
 *
 * Serve podcast episodes.
 */
router.get('/podcast/:dayId', async (req, res) => {

  let dayIdStr = req.params.dayId;

  let filepath = path.join(__dirname, "../podcast/" + dayIdStr + ".mp3");
  if (!fs.existsSync(filepath)) {
    console.log("Error in serving podcast episode " + dayIdStr);
    res.redirect("/404");
  }
  res.sendFile(filepath);
});


/**
 *
 * GET /podcast
 *
 * Serve RSS feed to podcast
 */
router.get('/podcast', async (req, res) => {

  let filepath = path.join(__dirname, `../podcast/podcast.xml`)
  //res.contentType('application/xml');
  res.sendFile(filepath);

});
```

I understand that I need to add a header `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, set the response header to `206 Partial Response`, and send the bytes requested by the header. The related thread [iTunes Range requests; podcast is rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978335/itunes-range-requests-podcast-is-rejected) answers the second one only. The [express-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-range) package has documentation only for JSON objects.

How can I code these three conditions in NodeJS?

Comment: It's not clear enough what's not working. Did you implement that other answer code (with a 206 response, etc)? If so, does it work? If it doesn't work, what's the error? same questions for the xml file.

Comment: According to their doc, [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) and the underlying [send](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) supports byte range request out of the box. Using nginx or another webserver/file hosting is even better, don't reinvent the wheel and write byte range request support from scratch.

Comment: @EricWong I want to keep track of the number of downloads of these podcasts, hence I want to code them in the NodejS server. I'll give serve-static a try on Sunday, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @OfirD What's not working is that I don't even know where to start in programming these three conditions. The above code works for serving complete files and keeping track of requests and downloads. It's not supported by Apple because of byte-range.

Comment: @miguelmorin I see, there are actually not too complicated methods of tracking download count on nginx, basically [just log the req and count the log file](https://serverfault.com/questions/313298/how-do-i-keep-the-download-count-of-a-url-in-nginx). You should really consider to use a webserver as nodejs is probably like"10x slower" than web server, plus nodejs is single-threaded so even serving a file hinders performance of other codes.

Comment: @EricWong I like the idea of using a separate server so podcast serving is not interrupted by server upgrades. I can configure a sub-domain. Could you write or point to an answer about serving byte-range files in Nginx tracking counts and IP of origin?

Comment: For serving byte range requests (files on local storage), nginx supports that ootb, no config required. Tracking download count is discussed in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/313298/how-do-i-keep-the-download-count-of-a-url-in-nginx). I cannot find resources about IP tracking, but you should be able to use similar approach, i.e. logging with specific format and use command line utilities like `cut` `wc` to count IPs

Answer (score 1):

### native support from Express

Express's `sendFile` supports byte-range requests out of the box (like `send` mentioned in the comments). You just need to add the 206 status code:

```js
res.status(206);
res.sendFile(filepath);
```

### debug

To debug whether your server is working, take these steps:

- Verify that the server supports byte-range requests by requesting 20 bytes; if the result is 21, you got the right number of bytes (taken from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/547073/test-a-server-for-byte-range-support)):

```
$ curl --silent --range 20-40 https://emotionathletes.org/podcast/1.mp3 | wc -c
21
```

- test the response code in the head when you request the whole file:

```
$ curl --head https://emotionathletes.org/podcast/1.mp3
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
```

- test the response code and the byte range when you request a range (this one may be redundant)

```
$ curl -H Range:bytes=20-40 -I https://emotionathletes.org/podcast/1.mp3
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
```

You can also test this with `wget` instead of `curl`, e.g.:

```
wget --header="Range: bytes=20-40" -t 1 https://emotionathletes.org/podcast/1.mp3
```

You can install `wget` on `macOS` with `brew`.

### still failing? Check the XML feed

If all this works and you still get a validation failure on iTunes connect, the problem may be you XML feed. Consider copying the structure of an XML feed that works on iTunes connect (such as [mine](https://emotionathletes.org/podcast-feed)), or ask for specific help.

In my case, I was serving podcasts identified with `/podcast/1` and iTunes did not even try downloading them because they lacked an extension. iTunes requested the feed with user agents `iTMS` and `Jakarta`, but did not request the episodes. Comparing to a successful feed, I realized that I needed an extension, so I used that.

### building the XML feed in NodeJS

You can also build the RSS feed from NodeJS with the [`rss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss) package. The attributes are a little tricky, e.g. [iTunes needs an enclosure with the url](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8090121), so I copy my part of my `podcast.js` here. For simplicity, I compiled it into a static XML file with `node podcast.js`, then served like any other static file.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const RSS = require('rss');
 
/* lets create an rss feed */
var feed = new RSS({
    itunesExplicit: false,
    title: 'Ginja',
    description: 'Um curso virtual que desenvolve a inteligência emocional nas crianças',
    feed_url: 'https://emocoes.org/podcast-feed',
    site_url: 'https://emocoes.org',
    image_url: 'http://emocoes.org/images/logo_podcast.png',
    managingEditor: 'Miguel Morin',
    webMaster: 'Miguel Morin',
    copyright: '2020 Atletismo Emocional',
    language: 'pt',
    categories: ['Education for Kids','Stories for Kids','Mental Health'],
    pubDate: 'October 20, 2020 22:00:00 GMT',
    ttl: '60',
    custom_namespaces: {
      'itunes': 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'
    },
  custom_elements: [
    {'itunes:explicit': 'no'},
      {'itunes:subtitle': 'Atletismo Emocional para crianças'},
      {'itunes:author': 'Ginja'},
      {'itunes:summary': 'Olá crianças! Eu sou o Ginja, o guru das emoções! Ao longo de várias aventuras com os meus amigos, vamos aprender a reconhecer, aceitar e utilizar as nossas emoções. E no fim, vamos ser uns atletas emocionais e chegar à meta da felicidade.\n\nVisitem a minha página: https://emocoes.org\n\nSigam-me no Facebook: https://facebook.com/emotionathletes\n\nSigam-me no Instagram: https://instagram.com/emotionathletes\n\nSigam-me no Twitter: https://twitter.com/emotionathletes'},
      {'itunes:owner': [
        {'itunes:name': 'Ginja'},
        {'itunes:email': 'ginja@emocoes.org'}
      ]},
      {'itunes:image': {
        _attr: {
          href: 'http://emocoes.org/images/logo_podcast.png'
        }
      }},
      {'itunes:category': [
        {_attr: {
          text: 'Kids & Family'
        }},
        {'itunes:category': {
          _attr: {
            text: 'Education for Kids'
          }
        }}
      ]}
    ]
});
 
/* loop over data and add to feed */
feed.item({
    title:  '1: Bem-vindos!',
    description: 'O Ginja explica que as emoções são como as ondas do mar. (Mensagem principal: As emoções são como as ondas do mar: vêm e vão, não as podemos parar.)',
    url: 'https://emocoes.org/podcast/1.mp3', // link to the item
    date: 'October 20, 2020 22:00:00 GMT', // any format that js Date can parse.
    custom_elements: [
      {'itunes:author': 'Ginja'},
      {'itunes:subtitle': 'O Ginja explica que as emoções são como as ondas do mar. (Mensagem principal: As emoções são como as ondas do mar: vêm e vão, não as podemos parar.)'},
      {'itunes:duration': '4:23'},
      {'enclosure url="https://emocoes.org/podcast/1.mp3" length="8520238" type="audio/mpeg"': {}}
    ]
});

var xml = feed.xml({indent: true});
let filepath = path.join(__dirname, `./public/podcast.xml`)
fs.writeFile(filepath, xml, (err) => {if (err) throw err;});
```

### other options

The comments mentioned `nginx` as a podcast server. I could not find how to do it and asked about it on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039346/nginx-podcast-server-with-byte-range-requests).